# Viewing Xps document - Compressed part has inconsistent data length

Tags: xpsdocument, xpsviewer, fixeddocument

```
XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.Read);
documentViewer.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
```

Second line gives next error: Compressed part has inconsistent data length

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found an answer.

I have created Xps document in this way:

```
Package package = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package);
```

Thus, after saving it and trying to view I got Compressed part has inconsistent data length error.

Then I changed

```
Package package = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package);
```

to

```
XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

And it started working.

Hope this will help somebody who may face with it.